# Access a variable in a class from another class in java

Tags: java

I am trying to access the value in Class01 class from Class02 class. I have been reading all night but I just can't get it to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I apologize if this seems like a dumb question but I am totally new to java. Thank you :-)

```
public class Class01 
{
    private JFrame frame;

    private RecordValue recAction = new RecordValue();

    private JButton btnAdd;
    private JButton btnEdit;

    //  Launch the application
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Class01 window = new Class01();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //  Create the application
    public Class01() {
        initialize();
    }

    //  Initialize the contents of the frame
    private void initialize()
    {       
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 228, 196));
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 197, 89);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
        btnAdd.setBounds(25, 11, 60, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnAdd);

        btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");
        btnEdit.setBounds(95, 11, 60, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnEdit);

        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                recAction.setRecordValue(0);    // 0 = New, 1 = Edit                
                Class02 ar = new Class02(recAction);
                ar.recordForm();
            }
        }); 

        btnEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                recAction.setRecordValue(1);    // 0 = New, 1 = Edit                
                Class02 er = new Class02(recAction);
                er.recordForm();
            }
        });
    }   

    public int getNewEditAction() 
    {
        System.out.println("getNewEditAction = " + this.recAction.getRecordValue());
        return this.recAction.getRecordValue();
    }       
}
//*************************************************************************************************
public class Class02{

    private JFrame frame;

    RecordValue _recordValue;
    Class01 c01 = new Class01();

    //  Launch the application
    public void recordForm() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {                   
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //  Create the application
    public Class02(RecordValue recordValue) 
    {
        _recordValue = recordValue;
        initialize();
    }

    //  Initialize contents of frame
    private void initialize() 
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 230, 95);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnShowAction = new JButton("Show Action Value");
        btnShowAction.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        btnShowAction.setBounds(28, 11, 163, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnShowAction);

        btnShowAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Rec Value = " + _recordValue);

            }
        });     
    }
}
//*************************************************************************************************
public class RecordValue 
{   
    public int _recordValue = 0;

    public int getRecordValue()
    {
        return _recordValue;
    }

    public void setRecordValue(int val)
    {
        _recordValue = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which variable?

Comment: My apologies, I been up all night. Can't think straight anymore. The variable is neweditAction

Comment: @Mnk you do `int recAction = ht.getNewEditAction();`, What's wrong with that ? It gives you `neweditAction`

Comment: I get a 0 instead of the value that I have it which is 1. I am completely lost as to why the value is not getting passed. I don't know if maybe I am doing it wrong.

Comment: In HealhTracker class, when the user clicks the btnUpdate then I assign a 1 to the neweditAction variable. Then when NewEditRecord class loads it should pull the value from that variable. But for some reason is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why isn't it working?**
You have a few problems with your code, but the main reason why it isn't working how you want is because of scope. Unless a variable is marked as *static*, it is a member of the class it's contained in, meaning each class will have its own version of that variable. Think of it like a simple pen - the ink inside the pen is part of that pen, and no two pens share ink. If you write with one pen it does not affect how much ink is in another pen.

**How to make it work**
There's a simple but improper way to fix this, and a slightly more complicated but proper way:

- Simple: Make *neweditAction* static so all instances of *HealthTracker* share the same instance of the variable, similar to all pens sharing the same ink.
- Proper: Make another class that contains the value, and change the value through the class. Pass the instance of the class around to who needs it.

I'm not going to bother showing you the simple solution because a) it's trivial, and b) it's the wrong way to solve your problem from a programming standpoint. I copied all of your code verbatim and commented out the pieces I didn't have the rest of your code for, then made changes to show you the *proper* solution. I focused on fixing the problem you describe here and ignored the other issues I saw:

```
public class RecordValue {
    private int _recordValue = 0;

    public int getRecordValue(){
        return _recordValue;
    }

    public void setRecordValue(int val){
        _recordValue = val;
    }
}

public class HealthTracker {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton btnNew;
    private JLabel lblHealthTrackerSystem;
    private JButton btnSearch;

    public JTable tblMain;
    // use an object type so we can pass it around and change the value(s)
    private RecordValue newEditAction = new RecordValue();
    //private int neweditAction;  // 0 = New, 1 = Edit
    public String servId;

    //  Public items
    //StoredProcedures sp = new StoredProcedures();
    String[] inputFlds = new String[3];
    private JButton btnDelete;

    //  Launch the application
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    HealthTracker window = new HealthTracker();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //  Create the application
    public HealthTracker() 
    {
        initialize();
    }

    //  Initialize the contents of the frame
    private void initialize()
    {
        btnNew = new JButton("Add New Record");
        btnNew.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        btnNew.setBounds(306, 276, 125, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNew);

        JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update Record");
        btnUpdate.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        btnUpdate.setBounds(576, 276, 125, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnUpdate);      

        //  Add a New Record Button        
        btnNew.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                newEditAction.setRecordValue(0);// = 0; // 0 = New, 1 = Edit

                // WE ALREADY HAVE ONE. DON'T MAKE ANOTHER ONE.
                NewEditRecord nr = new NewEditRecord(newEditAction);
                nr.recordForm();
            }
        });


        //  Update a Record Button
        btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                servId = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Which ServiceID Record You Want to Update?");
                newEditAction.setRecordValue(1);// = 1; // 0 = New, 1 = Edit 

                NewEditRecord ur = new NewEditRecord(newEditAction);
                ur.recordForm();
            }
        });
    }

    public int getNewEditAction() 
    {
        System.out.println("getNewEditAction = " + this.newEditAction.getRecordValue());
        return this.newEditAction.getRecordValue();
    }
}

public class NewEditRecord {
    private JFrame frame;

    // we don't need an entire tracker to do anything in here
    //HealthTracker ht = new HealthTracker();
    RecordValue _recordValue;
    //int recAction = ht.getNewEditAction();

    //  Launch the application
    // there is no reason for this to be static
    public /*static*/ void recordForm() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {                   
                    // don't make ANOTHER instance, we're in one already!!!!!!
                    //NewEditRecord window = new NewEditRecord();
                    /*window.*/frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //  Create the application
    public NewEditRecord(RecordValue recordValue) {
        _recordValue = recordValue;
        initialize();
    }

    //  Initialize contents of frame
    private void initialize() {
//        frame = new JFrame();
//        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 706, 390);
//        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
//
//        txtInstitution = new JTextField();
//        txtInstitution.setBounds(100, 47, 540, 20);
//        lblInstitution.setLabelFor(txtInstitution);
//        frame.getContentPane().add(txtInstitution);
//        txtInstitution.setColumns(10);
//
//        //  If Updating, Load Fields w/Record Data      
//        if (recAction == 1){
//            String qry = "SELECT ServiceID, Institution, Doctor, CONCAT(Street,', ',City, ', ', State, ' ', ZipCode) AS Address, Date, Cost"
//                        + ", Caption AS ServiceType, Comments FROM Services s INNER JOIN ServiceTypes st ON s.ServiceTypeID = st.ServiceTypeID"
//                        + " WHERE (ServiceID = '"+ recServID + "')";
//
//            try{
//                Connection dbconn = StoredProcedures.dbConn();
//                Statement stmt = dbconn.createStatement();
//                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry);
//
//                while (rs != null && rs.next()){
//                    txtInstitution.setText(rs.getString("ServiceID"));
//                }   
//            }
//            catch (Exception e){
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }           
//        }
//
//        //  Close Form
//        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
//            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
//                frame.dispose();
//            }
//        });
    }
}
```

Instead of trying to access the integer value contained within **HealthTracker**, which will be a different one for every instance, we are passing a single instance of an object into each **NewEditRecord**. This means all the **NewEditRecord** objects are pointing to the same **RecordValue** object, so if one of the **NewEditRecord** objects changes the value of **RecordValue** it will be reflect in the other **NewEditRecord** objects because they have to go to that one **RecordValue** and fetch the integer from there.

Comment: @Mnk correct, you should **not** be make a new instance - you should pass the existing instance *into* the NewEditRecord class instead such that you have access to that instance's copy of the value you're after.

Comment: I apologize but I really don't understand the code you put there. The NewHealthRecord class, is that something I have to create separate from what I already have? Again I apologize, this is my first time doing java and working with eclipse. I been up all night reading and doing research but I just can't make it work.

Comment: @Mnk sorry - typo.

Comment: Where is your syntax error? You will have to remove your existing initializations of NewEditRecord, and this constructor will replace the existing one for NewEditRecord. The initialization piece, i.e. using **new**, should replace the existing one(s). I updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: Unfortunately I still cant get this to work, if anyone can help me I would really appreciate it. I have been working and doing research, but even someone that is familiar with java looked at the code and couldn't see why is not working. Thank you.

Comment: @Mnk please see my new answer. Whoever you talked to that is "familiar with java" has no idea what they are doing.

Comment: Ok, I see what you did and implemented your code. The only thing is when I display the value of the "_recordValue" I get the following: "RecordValue@3d0c7ee1". I updated the code with a small app I created to get this going. Again I apologize if I am missing something simple, I am really trying to learn all this as I go along.

Comment: @Mnk that's because you are calling *toString()* on an object (*RecordValue*) that does not have an implementation of *toString()*, and therefore the default that gets spit out is the name of the reference. Instead, you should do *_recordValue.getRecordValue()* which will give you the integer value. See my code for *HealthTracker.getNewEditAction()*

Comment: I apologize, that was a silly mistake on my behalf. I thank you so much for all your help.